# What is the point of loading logs in Riverwood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm not talking about cutting wood, but on the platform you can load a log into some contraption that will push it through a saw and it will cut the log in half.

Do I get anything for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so. This appears to be an action included in the game to give the appearance of NPC's working in day-to-day jobs. Other examples include pushing a grain mill, or the NPC-only sweeping the floor, stacking firewood or tilling the fields.

Comment: It would be fun to "train" strenght or stamina by doint labours like that. (Hint to the modders)

Comment: @marto - Strength doesn't exist in The Elder Scrolls games any more, so modders would have to choose some other effect. A common misconception about the sawmills is that they affect rebuilding the walls and structures in a town after a dragon attack or siege -- it actually doesn't. I was disappointed when I found this out, so that might be a good feature to include in a mod.